# Find out memory leaks in a shared library between dlopen and dlclose

Tags: memory-leaks, shared-libraries, memcheck

We write a shared library(say slib.so) which is dlopen'ed, used and dlclose'd in a never-ending executable.
I want to check for memory leaks in the library slib.so without attaching the executable.

Is there any tool in Linux to find out the memory leaks in a shared library? So I need a tool which monitors the heap between dlopen and dlclose and report the issues after dlclose.

Answer (score 0):

> I need a tool which monitors the heap between dlopen and dlclose and report the issues after dlclose.

Any of the standard leak detection tools will work: Valgrind, Leak Sanitizer, TCMalloc heap checker, etc.

All you need to do is write a trivial executable wrapper, something like:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
  for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
    void *h = dlopen("libslib.so", RTLD_NOW);
    // optionally exercise the library here.
    dlclose(h);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This takes a lot of time as our executable does so much of things before calling our library.

Comment: @Srikanth That's why you create a *separate* trivial executable to just exercise the library.